# CSS float column extending over footer

Tags: html, css, css-float

I  am having a problem with my CSS whereby the right hand column in a 2 column layout is extending beyond the footer.

I have tried playing with the `clear: both;` property but I cannot get it to work..

[image has expired]

the second column has the id `column2` both columns use the class `column`. The footer html has the id `footerWrapper`

Both columns and footer are `div` tags.

My CSS (abridged):

```
.column {
    width: 49%;
}

#column2 {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#footerWrapper {
    background-color: #333333;
    border-top: 2px #FF6600 solid;
    color: #666;
}
```

HTML abridged:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div id="mainColumns"> 
      <div id="mainContainer"><div class="mainWrapper"> 
      <h1>Title</h2> 
    </div> 
    <!-- start panels --> 
    <div class="panels"> 
      <div class="column"> 
        <h2><img src="../lib/icons/newspaper.png" width="16" height="16">Title</h2> 
        <div> 
          <p>content</p> 
        </div> 
        <p></p> 
        <h2><img src="../lib/icons/rainbow.png" width="16" height="16">Title</h2> 
        <div> 
          <p>content</p> 
        </div> 
        <p></p> 
        <h2><img src="../lib/icons/rainbow.png" width="16" height="16">Title</h2>
        <div> 
          <p>content</p> 
        </div> 
      </div> 
      <div class="column" id="column2"> 
        <h2><img src="../lib/icons/newspaper.png" width="16" height="16">Title</h2> 
        <div> 
          <p>content</p> 
        </div> 
        <p></p> 
        <h2><img src="../lib/icons/rainbow.png" width="16" height="16">Title</h2> 
        <div> 
          <p>content</p> 
        </div> 
        <p></p> 
        <h2><img src="../lib/icons/rainbow.png" width="16" height="16">Title</h2>
        <div> 
          <p>content</p> 
        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
    <!-- end panels --> 
    <div class="mainWrapper"></p> 
      </div></div> 
      <div id="sideBar"> </div>
    </div> 
    <div id="footerWrapper"> 
      <div id="footer"> 
        <h6></h6> 
      </div> 
    </div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: We'll need to see some HTML too.

Comment: http://css.find-info.ru/css/011/ch05lev1sec4.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Float both columns
- Remove position, top and margin-left from #column2
- Add [clearfix](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200603/new_clearing_method_needed_for_ie7/) CSS to your stylesheet
- Add "clearfix" class to your panels div

Clearfix causes the panels div to wrap both columns, causing to be as tall as the longest column.

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow: auto` to your container.

Comment: Thanks SLaks: Doing this adds a scrollbar to the right hand side of the container, which doesn't really solve my problem. Is there a way to not show the scroll bars?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `clear:both;` to your `#footerwrapper`.

Or, you can manually insert an invisible element to clear the float, e.g. the following at the bottom of `div.panels`:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of scrollbars, you can add `overflow: hidden` to your container. It'll keep your escaping content hidden, although it might be better not to hide important information.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an error caused by editing your HTML to include in the question, but you have a few mismatched `<div>` tags in there.  Check that's all ok in your original.